# Using SOAP based webservice with Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

I have a requirement to use a SOAP based webservice with Python. Having looked at a couple of the options; SUDS and Zeep, they both work but both are way too slow to use in production (SUDS takes about 15 seconds, and Zeep takes six seconds).

My understanding is that the XML Parsing is what slows both down.

Are there are faster libraries, or it is better to try and write something from scratch?

Comment: Did you do some profiling to analyze the performance of the application and found the parsing to be the problem or are you assuming? Unless the XML you get back is very large, parsing it should not take 15 seconds no matter what library you use.

Comment: cProfile says it's running okay.

647 function calls (641 primitive calls) in 0.001 seconds

(output too long for a comment).

cProfile.run('re.compile("result = client.service.GetWhereAmIAttributes(''XXX'',E,N)")')

But running the line below takes >10 seconds.

result = client.service.GetWhereAmIAttributes('ConCase',E,N)

So either cProfile is mis-reporting, or there's something about the results (and it's a small amount of data returned) being loaded into the result var.